# Finding miminally overlapping recurrent intervals in R

Tags: r, intervals

I have a dataframe with `Start` and `End` sites that delimit an interval

The `sampleID` column denotes different individuals.

Example Input would be:

```
sampleID Start End
S1       10    20
S2       15    20
S3       5     15
S4       15    25
```

Example output is:

```
Start  End   sampleIDs   count
15     20    S1,S2,S4    3
10     15    S1,S3       2
5      10    S3          1
20     25    S4          1
```

which shows minimally overlapping intervals across `sampleID`s ranked by the number of `sampleID`s (`count`) that harbour that interval. Note that these intervals are intersections not unions, i.e. minimally overlapping.

Is there an efficient way to do this in R?

I have put below a larger input dataframe, which again is not exhaustive but demonstrates that scalability is needed.

```
structure(list(sampleID = c("S.A1.A0SB", "S.A1.A0SD", "S.A1.A0SE", 
"S.A1.A0SF", "S.A1.A0SH", "S.A1.A0SJ", "S.A1.A0SK", "S.A1.A0SO", 
"S.A1.A0SO", "S.A1.A0SO", "S.A1.A0SO", "S.A1.A0SP", "S.A1.A0SP", 
"S.A1.A0SP", "S.A1.A0SP", "S.A1.A0SP", "S.A1.A0SP", "S.A1.A0SP", 
"S.A1.A0SP", "S.A2.A04N", "S.A2.A04Q", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", 
"S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", 
"S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04U", "S.A2.A04V", "S.A2.A04W", 
"S.A2.A04Y", "S.A2.A04Y", "S.A2.A04Y", "S.A2.A0CK", "S.A2.A0CL", 
"S.A2.A0CL", "S.A2.A0CL", "S.A2.A0CL", "S.A2.A0CL", "S.A2.A0CL", 
"S.A2.A0CO", "S.A2.A0CP", "S.A2.A0CU", "S.A2.A0CW", "S.A2.A0CZ", 
"S.A2.A0CZ", "S.A2.A0D1", "S.A2.A0D2", "S.A2.A0D2", "S.A2.A0D2", 
"S.A2.A0D2", "S.A2.A0D2", "S.A2.A0D3", "S.A2.A0D4", "S.A2.A0EM", 
"S.A2.A0EO", "S.A2.A0EO", "S.A2.A0ET", "S.A2.A0EX", "S.A2.A0EX", 
"S.A2.A0EX", "S.A2.A0SW", "S.A2.A0SW", "S.A2.A0SX", "S.A2.A0SX", 
"S.A2.A0SX", "S.A2.A0SX", "S.A2.A0SX", "S.A2.A0SY", "S.A2.A0T0", 
"S.A2.A0T0", "S.A2.A0T0", "S.A2.A0T0", "S.A2.A0T2", "S.A2.A0T3", 
"S.A2.A0T3", "S.A2.A0T3", "S.A2.A0T5", "S.A2.A0T5", "S.A2.A0T5", 
"S.A2.A0T5", "S.A2.A0T7", "S.A2.A0T7", "S.A2.A0YC", "S.A2.A0YC", 
"S.A2.A0YC", "S.A2.A0YD", "S.A2.A0YD", "S.A2.A0YE", "S.A2.A0YE", 
"S.A2.A0YF", "S.A2.A0YF", "S.A2.A0YG", "S.A2.A0YH", "S.A2.A0YH", 
"S.A2.A0YI", "S.A2.A0YK"), Start = c(61949885L, 14267730L, 155824310L, 
61934790L, 45924211L, 102529319L, 162513149L, 51815687L, 80466481L, 
116281984L, 123138522L, 60345L, 8866808L, 11707881L, 28154465L, 
38352136L, 50457227L, 74874773L, 106301415L, 146302036L, 170198898L, 
60345L, 5188432L, 12147403L, 16475012L, 34606495L, 42058455L, 
78861145L, 89338676L, 190742772L, 190953557L, 61960972L, 146256066L, 
12006772L, 102364297L, 117352205L, 3970428L, 60345L, 55855976L, 
140288130L, 143825638L, 152172182L, 193601448L, 3959916L, 141061438L, 
182730173L, 85483972L, 48649406L, 117438564L, 171199568L, 60345L, 
8933583L, 41810481L, 56447761L, 60041687L, 21999782L, 165040863L, 
160272760L, 61960972L, 98726948L, 194106553L, 38102115L, 45117006L, 
69922067L, 27068426L, 61964568L, 60345L, 34165785L, 79359090L, 
137778574L, 196897088L, 4588788L, 48924900L, 182637122L, 185982713L, 
197683775L, 60345L, 60345L, 36157091L, 75901451L, 4588300L, 8896114L, 
61960972L, 113218206L, 151910714L, 161570016L, 45731451L, 97773946L, 
126685000L, 76434706L, 146256066L, 97773946L, 129775858L, 146257307L, 
151910714L, 16263872L, 36154008L, 122011351L, 45734818L, 104890278L
), End = c(61968443L, 14500744L, 155858773L, 61963289L, 70473655L, 
102854965L, 162623881L, 53767689L, 80473220L, 123055274L, 126487533L, 
8820401L, 11571603L, 28148832L, 38347851L, 48581848L, 72694005L, 
89508500L, 106347238L, 146309472L, 171216876L, 3079965L, 9796508L, 
14448975L, 25426775L, 40270066L, 78613247L, 86491493L, 89426646L, 
190858147L, 190980956L, 61963289L, 146367621L, 12010549L, 102616251L, 
119730589L, 3972228L, 55763091L, 117372597L, 140853186L, 149511080L, 
157470885L, 197896118L, 3976417L, 141181684L, 182829544L, 85722302L, 
52140767L, 117976887L, 171348970L, 8917703L, 41700718L, 56329310L, 
59429073L, 151645022L, 22000946L, 165095753L, 160317817L, 61963289L, 
98734044L, 194143040L, 39488541L, 45133774L, 73275553L, 61960484L, 
62624801L, 33315307L, 75276213L, 102197415L, 137787173L, 197896118L, 
4607133L, 52203291L, 185970173L, 190759854L, 197896118L, 93519478L, 
36153983L, 75394435L, 87892515L, 4607133L, 9089254L, 61963289L, 
113257213L, 152987815L, 162447684L, 45763977L, 97787341L, 128128083L, 
76464137L, 146277132L, 97787849L, 129806236L, 146260941L, 151978186L, 
16389026L, 36156863L, 122022417L, 45765778L, 104987434L), length = c(18558L, 
233014L, 34463L, 28499L, 24549444L, 325646L, 110732L, 1952002L, 
6739L, 6773290L, 3349011L, 8760056L, 2704795L, 16440951L, 10193386L, 
10229712L, 22236778L, 14633727L, 45823L, 7436L, 1017978L, 3019620L, 
4608076L, 2301572L, 8951763L, 5663571L, 36554792L, 7630348L, 
87970L, 115375L, 27399L, 2317L, 111555L, 3777L, 251954L, 2378384L, 
1800L, 55702746L, 61516621L, 565056L, 5685442L, 5298703L, 4294670L, 
16501L, 120246L, 99371L, 238330L, 3491361L, 538323L, 149402L, 
8857358L, 32767135L, 14518829L, 2981312L, 91603335L, 1164L, 54890L, 
45057L, 2317L, 7096L, 36487L, 1386426L, 16768L, 3353486L, 34892058L, 
660233L, 33254962L, 41110428L, 22838325L, 8599L, 999030L, 18345L, 
3278391L, 3333051L, 4777141L, 212343L, 93459133L, 36093638L, 
39237344L, 11991064L, 18833L, 193140L, 2317L, 39007L, 1077101L, 
877668L, 32526L, 13395L, 1443083L, 29431L, 21066L, 13903L, 30378L, 
3634L, 67472L, 125154L, 2855L, 11066L, 30960L, 97156L)), .Names = c("sampleID", 
"Start", "End", "length"), row.names = c(18L, 130L, 252L, 420L, 
707L, 921L, 1310L, 2173L, 2181L, 2191L, 2193L, 2585L, 2587L, 
2592L, 2594L, 2596L, 2598L, 2600L, 2602L, 2762L, 3217L, 3896L, 
3898L, 3901L, 3903L, 3905L, 3911L, 3913L, 3915L, 3940L, 3942L, 
4422L, 4647L, 5131L, 5135L, 5137L, 5336L, 5479L, 5481L, 5488L, 
5492L, 5498L, 5500L, 6080L, 6178L, 6749L, 7529L, 8218L, 8224L, 
8924L, 9198L, 9200L, 9202L, 9204L, 9206L, 9487L, 9652L, 9825L, 
10010L, 10012L, 10839L, 11487L, 11489L, 11491L, 12297L, 12299L, 
12445L, 12447L, 12450L, 12452L, 12469L, 12650L, 12786L, 12794L, 
12796L, 12798L, 13317L, 13510L, 13512L, 13514L, 13964L, 13968L, 
13976L, 13978L, 14370L, 14372L, 14573L, 14577L, 14583L, 14956L, 
14958L, 15084L, 15086L, 15296L, 15298L, 15495L, 15753L, 15755L, 
15934L, 16343L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your question is not particularly clear and your data doesn't match your question example. How do you define a `sampleID`  that 'harbours the interval'?

Comment: The larger data example is to see whether it will work on a more complicated dataframe. I'm not sure what you mean it doesn't "match". The first example where I also provide example output is a very simple example that could be hard-coded. If the sampleID interval spans the minimal overlap interval (e.g. rows in example output) then it "harbours the minimal overlap interval"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very experiences with data.table, but here's a try on which you can build up:

```
library(data.table)
data <- fread("sampleID Start End
S1       10    20
S2       15    20
S3       5     15
S4       15    25")
setkey(data, Start, End)
startsEnds <- data.table(Start = head(sort(unique(c(data$Start, data$End))), -1), 
                         End = tail(sort(unique(c(data$Start, data$End))), -1))
(dt <- foverlaps(startsEnds, data, type="within")[,c(.(sampleIDs=lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=",")), count=.N), by=.(Start=i.Start, End=i.End), .SDcols="sampleID"][order(-count)])
#    Start End sampleIDs count
# 1:    15  20  S1,S2,S4     3
# 2:    10  15     S3,S1     2
# 3:     5  10        S3     1
# 4:    20  25        S4     1
```

You may want to adjust how the `startsEnds` table is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using a cross join. It is super inefficient.

```
library(dplyr)

times = 
  data %>% select(time = Start) %>%
  bind_rows(data %>% select(time = End)) %>%
  distinct %>%
  arrange(time)

# create a to-from table
envelopes =
  times %>% 
  rename(start_time.envelope = time) %>% 
  slice(-n()) %>%
  bind_cols(times %>% 
              rename(end_time.envelope = time) %>% 
              slice(-1)) %>%
  mutate(envelope_ID = 1:n())

# cross join
join_table = 
  data %>%
  merge(envelopes) %>%
  filter(pmax(Start, start_time.envelope) < 
           pmin(End, end_time.envelope) )

# summarize
summary =
  join_table %>%
  group_by(envelope_ID) %>%
  summarize(sampleIDs = sampleID %>% paste(collapse = ";"),
            n = n()) %>%
  left_join(envelopes)
```